# What does the name Sheftel mean?

Tags: names

It seems that "Sheftel" is a name most commonly used by Jews, and has been [used](https://www.yutorah.org/rabbi-sheftel-neuberger/) by some [contemporary](http://kevarim.com/rabbi-sheftel-kramer/) Rabbinic figures in America, but I haven't come across its origin yet. What does the name mean?

Comment: Is it Ashkenazi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beis Shmuel (Even Haezer 129) [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Shmuel%2C_Beit_Shmuel_on_Names_for_Men.62?vhe=Vilna,_1876&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) it's a nickname (כינוי) for David, Yaakov or Shabsi.

Comment: I suppose because they were shepherds.

Comment: @interested Hadn't thought of that. Interesting idea, although then shouldn't it be a nickname for Moshe too?

Comment: Moshe already has ten names!